# How Do I Iterate Through Sheet Rows and Check if One Cell in Row is False?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I’m new to Java/Apps Script, and struggling with this function. Please forgive any glaring mistakes in my explanation!

In short, I have four separate sheets. Each of my company’s three contractors will have their own sheet in which to submit their invoice info, all of which is populated into a master sheet containing all of the contractor’s invoice information.

All of the sheets are set up as follows:
Column A: date
Column B: link to invoice
Column C: amount owed
Column D: checkbox indicating whether the invoice has been paid.

I want to use Apps Script in the master invoice tracking sheet to send an email notification to my company every morning if a row has data in A,B and C, but the checkbox D is still false (indicating that a invoice has been submitted, but not paid). I’ve set up the trigger to run the function every morning, but I can’t get the function itself to work.

How do I create a function that iterates through each row and checks if the first three columns === true, and column D === false?

I can’t figure out why Apps Script is giving a syntax error for the “)” on line 5, either.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
function notifyHelpdesk(){
let sally = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sally Smith");
let data = sally.getRange("A2:C41").getValues();
let i = data[0]

for(i,i = data[42],i++){
if (data[i][0] === true && data[i][1]===true && data [i][2]===true && data[i][3] ===false){
MailApp.sendEmail({
to: "genericaddress@company.net",
    subject: "New Invoice Submitted",
htmlBody: "A contractor has submitted a new invoice! Please find details in the Master Invoice    tracker sheet:www.fakelinktosheet.com"
});
}
}
}
```

//I wanted i to represent each row, and for the code to loop through all 41 rows of the sheet

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function notifyHelpdesk() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sally Smith");
  let vs1 = sh1.getRange("A2:D41").getValues();//you did not include column D in your function
  let i = vs1[0]
  vs.forEach((r, i) => {
    //just check for truthiness in first three columns
    if (r[0] && r[1] && r[2] && r[3] == false) {
      MailApp.sendEmail({
        to: "genericaddress@company.net",
        subject: "New Invoice Submitted",
        htmlBody: "A contractor has submitted a new invoice! Please find details in the Master Invoice    tracker sheet:www.fakelinktosheet.com"
      });
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! It worked in that it went through each row, but it ended up sending me 40 email notifications, even though only one row had values in columns A, B, and C. I did change it slightly:  vs1.forEach((r,i)=>{
  if (r[0] && r[1] && r[2] == true && r[3] == false)